# isset($_POST['Submit'] not set after submit

Tags: php, forms, post, button, submit

I know it seems to be a common problem but I searched a lot of them and nothing helped me. I have the following code and on Submit, nothing happens aside from a page reload. I tried with enctype and without, with `<input type=button ...>` and  `<button ...>` but I never got the echo...

```html
<?php

if (isset($_POST['Submit']) && !empty($_POST['Submit'])){
  echo 'It works';
} else {
?>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name" class="control-label">Name</label>
        <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name"
               aria-describedby="helpBlock"
               oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Bitte tragen Sie Ihren Namen ein.')"
               oninput="setCustomValidity('')"
               required>
    </div>

    <!-- multiple other form-groups like the first one -->

    <div class="form-group">
        <input name="Submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Abschicken">
    </div>
    <div id="helpBlock">* Alle Felder sind Pflichtfelder.</div>
</form>
<?php } ?>
```

UPDATE:

1. I run this code on localhost via xampp
2. deleting `!empty($_POST['Submit'])` doesn't help either
3. yes, it is a .php file

UPDATE:

And also if I try entering

`foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    echo 'index key ' . $key . ' value ' . $value . '<br>';}`

nothing shows up on the page - so I assume that the $_POST variable doesn't get set... can anybody tell why?

Comment: try to add a var_dump of your $_POST and see what you have

Comment: why don't you remove the form tag from the else block

Comment: works for me. What do you see? the page reloads, and your form shows blank again?

Comment: Copy/pasted this code onto my dev box - works fine. The `$_POST` array contains `["Submit"] => string(10) "Abschicken"` when you submit the form. So the question is: 1) are you running this on a web server and 2) is it a `.php` file (rather than `.html`)

Comment: how are you running this as, with a webserver and as `http://localhost` or directly in your browser as `file:///`?

Comment: @Fred-ii- man.. i guess that could still happen

Comment: @CodeGodie I'm thinking they're doing the latter of what I said in my comment. Spidey sense tells me ;-)

Comment: Tell me/us Julia, what do you see in your HTML source, "code"? if so, then see my first comment. Edit (ping): and @CD001 's comment also applies here.

Comment: Further to Fred's comment: After you submit the form, when you ask *the browser* to show you the source code, what do you see?

Comment: @Fred-ii- if that were the case though, wouldnt they see all the PHP code as HTML markup since, if they were to access `file:///`, PHP wont be running?

Comment: @CodeGodie Could be. However, I do remember a similar question with the same symptoms.

Comment: there's also some JS here, so the methods are unknown and how this is used. Up until that you can step in here to answer our questions Julia, your question will remain unclear/unanswered.

Comment: Julia is a ghost.. moving on.

Comment: I use http://localhost to run the code
@Fred-ii- what do you mean by what would I see in my source?

Comment: @CodeGodie you'd see the PHP when you View Source - but otherwise, since it starts with `<`, the browser will see it as a garbage HTML tag and just won't display it on the page.

Comment: @CD001 i disagree. The reason this will not be the case is because if they are using PHP code, you should also be using `.php` as your extension as opposed to `.html` . Since PHP does not run on `file:///` and the extension is `.php` then the browser will just display everything as text thus not needed to view the source.

Comment: @julia are you using the `.php` extension when running this in the url? as in `http://localhost/test.php` or are you using `.html` as in `http://localhost/test.html` ?

Comment: @CodeGodie - fair point, I was assuming the file was `.html` as well since that seems to go hand-in-hand with not running it on a server (though if you actually open a `.php` file in a browser it'll generally default to `html` depending on the settings); looking at the *update* though, neither seems to be the case here so I'm kinda stumped - it *should* work.

Comment: For testing purposes, temporarily delete the `<input name="name"` field, submit your form, and let us know what happens.

Comment: @CodeGodie I am using test.php
and when I delete the name-attribute, it happens the same thing - only the page reloads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the case: the problem was, that because of the URL `localhost[...]/test.php?nav=kontakt` the form always tried to execute a GET request. Now I have to use a static page instead of the `test.php` with parameter